# How are variables in GraphQL passed?

Tags: graphql

I am trying to add variables to a query to post data. I am following this example from GraphQL. How does the query detect the variables(i.e. "episode")? How do I pass the variables in? Do I add the keyword "variables" in front of the dictionary? I am executing the query in Python.

[image: GraphQL Example]

Comment: check network request ... follow some "python graphql mutation" tutorial

Comment: Not helpful, xadm.

Comment: Also this is clearly a query, not a mutation.

Comment: majority of queries are described/explained without using variables, almost all mutations requires variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how GraphQL variables are passed to a GraphQL API endpoint via a Python post request:

```py
r = requests.post(url,json={"query": query, "variables": variables},  headers=headers)
```

Also make sure the `Content-Type` header reads `application/json` not `application/graphql`